# How are sentient programs able to exist outside the Matrix, and what do they look like outside?

Tags: the-matrix

Sentient programs such as the Exiles or the Analyst are able to exist outside the Matrix and don't need it for survival. E.g. if there was a shutdown of the Matrix, the programs would survive, but where and how, given the fact they're programs from within the Matrix?

When the Truce was being made,

> the Analyst was present, but where exactly was he at that time? He couldn't have been inside the Matrix because all programs there were assimilated by Smith. So from where did he watch and listen?

And what do these programs look like while being outside the Matrix?

Comment: Why do you say they're programs within the Matrix? Surely they're programs in the machine world, which is connected to the Matrix.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Most are from the first two Matrices (Paradise and Hell Matrix). Where in the machine world are they when they aren't in the Matrix at the moment and what do they look like outside the Matrix?

Comment: @Valorum E.g. the Analyst said (spoiler warning) that he was there when the Truce was made. Where exactly was he? From where did he watch and listen? How did he look while outside the Matrix?

Comment: Could you add those details to the question (possibly telling us where you got them from).

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Alright I expanded a bit.

Comment: I don't think "what do they look like" is a question with any meaning. Programs have an appearance in the Matrix, because they interact with humans. Would they need that if they were only interacting with other programs?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Um, I don't know. That may be part of an answer. The Analyst has obviously "seen" and "heard" the negotiation of the Truce somehow. The Morpheus program has a certain appearance outside the Matrix, but that's a modal that was "freed" by a red pill. The other programs don't seem to need that.

Comment: Presumably some programs can have some kind of existence outside the Matrix in the [machine city](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/01)--the [Deus Ex Machina](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Deus_Ex_Machina) was some kind of intelligent AI and it hadn't been assimilated by Smith, for example. The Analyst may have been there, observing when the Deus Ex Machina negotiated with Neo, and that would also explain how he was able to recover Neo's body.